# How to add foreign key using a non public schema in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, database-schema, ddl

I am trying to add a foreign key with this psql command:

```
places_local=> ALTER TABLE prestamos_bienes.bienes
ADD CONSTRAINT "bienes_prestamos_bienes.marcas_id_marca_fk"
FOREIGN KEY (id_marca) REFERENCES "prestamos_bienes.marcas" (id_marca);
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: no existe la relación «prestamos_bienes.marcas»
```

It means:

```
ERROR: relation «prestamos_bienes.marcas» does not exist
```

The [PostgreSQL error](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/errcodes-appendix.html) codes is **42P01 (undefined_table)**.

My database is: **places_local**

My schema is: **prestamos_bienes**

My tables are: **bienes** and **marcas**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier `"prestamos_bienes.marcas"` is name **without** a schema qualification.

Each part of a fully qualified name needs to be quoted individually.

```
ALTER TABLE prestamos_bienes.bienes
   ADD CONSTRAINT "bienes_prestamos_bienes.marcas_id_marca_fk"
   FOREIGN KEY (id_marca) REFERENCES "prestamos_bienes"."marcas" (id_marca);
```

Or better without quotes completely:

```
ALTER TABLE prestamos_bienes.bienes
   ADD CONSTRAINT bienes_marcas_fk
   FOREIGN KEY (id_marca) REFERENCES prestamos_bienes.marcas (id_marca);
```

In general, you should avoid the use of double quotes completely.

Then it might also be clear what you intended with the foreign key name: `"bienes_prestamos_bienes.marcas_id_marca_fk"`. That also is **not** a schema qualified name.